# Control to display mix of text and links in wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is there any control in windows phone using which I can handle strings of type:

> @user1 commented on @user2's post on #page

Of the above string I want to handle clicks on `@user1`, `@user2` and `#page` navigating to local urls like `/MainPage.xaml?profile=user1` or `/MainPage.xaml?page=pagename`

Is there some way to do this?

I was thinking of a bad bad way earlier to divide my message string like:

- TextBlock1 --> user1
- TextBlock2 --> commented on
- TextBlock3 --> user2 etc....

But then I realized its not gonna work. There need to be generic way to do this. I also wish to assign different colors to each of the link if possible.

I can transform my string into something like:

> <>user1<> commented on <>@user2's<> post on <>#page<>

with `a` tags around. Is there some control for this? Can't user WebBrowser control.

Also this is not the only string I wish to handle of this type. String can be any other random text with user and page links in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RichTextBox control and put inside Hyperlink items:

```
  <RichTextBox>
    <Paragraph>
      <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink1_Click">@user1</Hyperlink>
      <Run Text=" commented on " />
      <Hyperlink Click="Hyperlink2_Click">@user2</Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
  </RichTextBox>
```

for the Hyperlink items you can either handle the Click event, or try directly to set a navigation uri that points to a local page.